# Using Angular's $location service to display a specific view based on current path

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

fairly new to Angular and have looked around this site fairly extensively, but most of the $location related threads I've found have to do with authentication and routing.

**My question is:** what is the best method for 1) setting up a watch on the current $location.path(), and 2) updating the view via a custom directive based on the current path?

I am currently using the ngView directive to update the majority of the page (routing works fine - no changes needed here). I now want to create a 'custom nav widget directive' that updates based on the current path, but doesn't need to go in my ngView templates (seems like a lot of repetitive code). To be clear - don't have any code written yet for the custom nav functionality. I am more looking for some guidance on best way to accomplish this and a rough outline on how.

```
<body>
 <div ng-view></div>
 <div custom-nav-widget-directive></div
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get that you want an answer that focuses on your suggested approach. But you might want to take a look at UI-Router. A powerful third-party alternative to the standard ngRouter.

UI-Router allows for **[Multiple Named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)**. You could have something like:

```
<body>
  <div ui-view>
  <div ui-view='nav'>
</body>
```

Where everything under **div[ui-view='nav']** can change independently from the rest of your page/app which would in turn render under **div[ui-view]**. This would keep your **nav logic and template(s)** apart from those of the rest of the app/page.

Once I got to know it, UI-Router made me decrease my need for directives. Each router state and its views need their own configuration object like normal routes-- or directives for that matter--, with a controller, template, etc... Pretty cool.

If you decide to give a try do let me know, I'd be glad to help kickstart the learning curve.

Comment: Would love to learn about this approach! Can you point me to some good resources?